# How to setup TypeScript with React in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, reactjs, typescript

I'm kinda new to TypeScript development but managed to grasp it rather quickly.
However I find myself frustrated with setting up a project with all these module loaders, compilers, settings and what not.

I'm trying to setup a working environment for TypeScript with React in Visual Studio 2017 but to no avail. I've tried the following:

**MyTestComponent.tsx**

```
/// <reference path="../typings/react/index.d.ts"/>

interface IProps {
    name: string
}

class MyTestComponent extends React.Component<IProps, {}> {
    render() {
        console.log("rendering component");
        return <span>{this.props.name}</span>;
    }
}
```

**App.ts**

```
/// <reference path="TsImports.ts"/>

class App {
    constructor() {
         console.log("app started");
         React.createElement(MyTestComponent,
            { name: "somename" },
            document.getElementById("someid"));
    }
}
```

**index.html**

```
<div id="someid"></div>

<script src="~/Scripts/app.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
   var app = new App();
</script>
```

I'm getting the "app started" in the console, but no rendered elements. I also don't get any console errors.

I've also tried the official tutorial from the typescript website in VS Code and it works. However I can't figure out what is the role of `Webpack` in the whole process. Could someone please explain with some detail how to set that up, or at least point me at some resources. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here's a repo a buddy of mine put together for getting started with react and typescript.  It's just a super-basic working implementation of react in typescript with redux (built with webpack).

https://github.com/drewschrauf/typescript-react-redux

Comment: he said he wants to do that in visual studio not visual code.

Comment: @Aflred Nothing about my answer has anything to do with Visual Studio Code.  It's a repo.  The editor you choose to use doesn't matter.  There's no hard dependency between VS and a React/TypeScript stack.  It's purely how you choose to run your watch/build tasks (which, again, is entirely editor-agnostic)